# Sampling random numbers with a certain condition.

Tags: statistics, random-variables, matlab, sampling

I want to randomly sample three variables that are conditioned by
$$x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3$$ and $x_1\in [0,\, \ell]$, $x_2\in [0,\, \ell-\ell_1]$ and $x_3 \in [0, \,\ell-\ell_1-\ell_2]$.

I have only limited statistics knowledge. Would you help me on how to do this using Matlab?

Comment: What do you mean by $\ell$ and the $\ell_i$?

Comment: Could you clarify your limits? How are l1, l2 determined? What is "O"...do you mean 0?

Comment: l and l1 and l2 are given numbers. 0 is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your ranges are inconsistent with your stated condition: $max(x_3)<max(x_2)<max(x_1)$ yet you are conditioning them to have the opposite general relationship. This will result in the actual range of x values being constrained to $x_3$'s interval of $[0, \,\ell-\ell_1-\ell_2]$.

To generate conditional values, you would choose them in succession:

1. Select $x_3$ from $[0, \,\ell-\ell_1-\ell_2]$
2. Select $x_2$ from $[0, x_3]$
3. Select $x_1$ from $[0, x_2]$

Of course, you need to decide on a distribution for the x's (perhaps uniform distribution?) but following the above will get you the correct conditional values.

Comment: I had an error in my problem statement regarding the intervals: x1 in [0, l1], x2 in [l2-x1,l2] and x3 in [l3-x2,l3].

Comment: @user119861 OK. Then to ensure consistency, your limits need to respect the following conditions: $\ell_2\geq 2\ell_1,\ell_3\geq 2\ell_2=4\ell_1$

Comment: Unfortunately the limit are physically given by the hardware underlying my system and do not fullfill these conditions. Thinking further about it, the intervals are x1 in [0,l1], x2 in [0, min(x1,l2)] and x3 in [0, min(l3,b2)].

Comment: @user119861 in that case, how could you satisfy your condition that X3>X2>X1? The above ranges *shrink* as you move from X1 to X3?

Comment: l1 > l2 > l3 and the condition x1 >= x2 >=x3. I am sorry about all the mistakes I made in posing the question...

Comment: @user119861 no worries, but please update your post to reflect what you mean. Its hard to piece together from comments.

Comment: @user119861 to sample from each interval, you need to decide on a distribution. Do you want there to be an equal chance of each possible value of x that satisfies your condition? If so, you just need to look up the command for a uniform distribution in MatLab.